# how to split a string based on extended ascii in java

Tags: java

I have a string which I need to split based on an extended ascii character. I know that I can do that by checking every character and its corresponding value is grater that 127 because normal ascii characters have value betn 0-127. but this is not an efficient way. is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: Do you mean specific extended ASCII char or any extended ASCII char?

Comment: Any string split function you can imagine will iterate at least once over the string, character by character. There is no other way.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is an incredibly vague term. Do you have a specific Unicode character in mind?

Comment: I mean a specific extended ascii char. actually I have to use extended ascii

Answer (score 4):

Use String's [split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with a negated character class. The class `[\x00-\x7F]` is all ascii characters, so `[^\x00-\x7F]` is all non-ascii characters (whether or not this is the same as "extended ascii" characters is another matter; the meaning of that term is vague, as Jon Skeet pointed out in the comments).

```
String[] result = String.split("[^\\x00-\\x7F]");
```

Note that this will split on all occurrences of a non-ascii character, so you might end up with empty strings in the result.